# Is there a way to use a non static method from another class? flutter

Tags: flutter

Id like to make a listtile which reacts to login state. So Ive made this code.

```
class LoginOrNot extends ChangeNotifier{
  bool _login = false;

  bool get login => _login;

  void toggle(){
    _login = !_login;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
ListTile(
                          title: LoginOrNot._login? Text("Sign out") : Text("Sign in"),
                          onTap:()
                            {LoginOrNot._login? a method : Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage(),));}
                        ),
```

because its not accessible from the listtile. I gets an error, also I found out I cant set those static cause of notifyListners. How can I use this method??

Comment: You can access Provider value and manage login state by current model. If you have to get info about login user or not call method from Provider.

Comment: you mean Provider package. dont you? I should look over it. thanks.